# engine.io / engine.io-client: transport switching does not occur

Tags: node.js, websocket, engine.io

I wrote this at server side:

```
var engine = require('engine.io'),
    server = engine.listen(49157, {
      transports: [ 'polling', 'websocket' ]
    });
```

I wrote this client side:

```
var socket = eio('ws://my.net:49157', {
  transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling' ]
});
```

It never succeeds to connect! Just 1 try then callbacks error.

It is supposed to switch protocol (from `'websocket'` to `'polling'`) when it fails. Why protocol switching does not occur? How can we make that switching work?

**Details**:

When I use the same `transports` value both on server and client, then **it works correctly**; i.e. connection **is good and fast** and is websocket-based only if `transports[0x0] === 'websocket'`, and connection is **also good** and is polling-based only if `transports[0x0] === 'polling'`.

As soon as connection fails, no retry is done using alternate transport.

Using engine.io 1.5.4.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: *to code my own protocol switcher*!

The idea is to use only one protocol in the `transports` array for each call to `eio()` client side. So we can use an array to traverse the protocols on protocol failures.

I wrote this:

```
// only on client side - server side stays untouched 
var socket,
  aTransports = ['polling', 'websocket'],
  iCurrentTranport = 0x0;


function doConnect() {
  "use strict";
  socket = eio('ws://my.net:49157', {
    transports: [ aTransports[iCurrentTranport++] ]
  });

  socket.on('open', function() {
    console.log('-connected-');
    socket.on('message', function(data){
      console.log(data);
    });
    socket.on('close', function(){console.log('+disconnected+');});
  });

  socket.on('error', function(z) {
    console.log('*error*', z);
    if (iCurrentTranport > 1) { iCurrentTranport = 0x0; return; }
    setTimeout(function () {
      doConnect();
    }, 500);
  });
}


// start ws connection
doConnect();
```

Only call `doConnect()` and the protocol switch works!

*Note: this code does not take care of error checks.*

Comment: is this still needed?